# orderBy array item value in Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get Angular's `ng-repeat` directive to sort a list by each item's actual value, rather than by the value of a property on each item?

eg:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'WHAT_GOES_HERE??'">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsbin.com/okatur/1/edit

I realize I could just do `.sort()` on the array, but is that my only option?

Comment: So you want to sort by whatever is in <code>{{item}}</code>?

Comment: Yes that's right - `$scope.items` being an array of primitives

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Since 1.3.0-rc.5

Since [AngularJS 1.3.0-rc.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/607f016a0ba705ce40df0164360fb96a9d7f5912), the `orderBy` filter (see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)) will automatically sort the array using its items if no additional parameters are provided.

```xml
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy">{{item}}</li>
```

<kbd>[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/okatur/59/edit)</kbd>

### Before 1.3.0-rc.5

The `orderBy` filter (see the [historical documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy)) can also take a function as second parameter, whose return value will be compared using the `<`, `=` and `>` operator.
You can simply use the `angular.identity` (see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.identity)) for that purpose:

```js
$scope.identity = angular.identity;
```

```xml
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:identity">{{item}}</li>
```

<kbd>[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/okatur/6/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Is it possible to refer to `angular.identity` directly in the markup, without having to save it to `$scope.identity` in the JS?

Comment: No. You can only access to variables defined in the `$scope` in the template.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can orderBy reverse with >1.3.0-rc.5 by using `orderBy:true:true`

Comment: @BradenSteffaniak Well, no, it doesn't work. Actually, since 1.3.0-rc.5, `array | orderBy` is equivalent to `array | orderBy:'+'`. If you want to sort in reverse order, you can therefore simply do `array | orderBy:'-'`. Give it a try with the first JS Bin link ;-) !

Answer (score 5):

You can try following.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'toString()'">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```