# Use the angular orderBy filter to reverse an array of Dates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

How do you use the `orderBy` filter to reverse an array of Dates? I can use `.sort().reverse()` on the model itself, but I'd rather let angular do it if possible

http://jsfiddle.net/V6aZH/2/

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('DatesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.dates = [ new Date(2013, 0, 1), new Date(2013, 1, 1) ];
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="DatesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="d in dates" ng-bind="d | date:'medium'"></div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result**

Feb 1, 2013 12:00:00 AM
Jan 1, 2013 12:00:00 AM

According to the docs, I'd expect to be able to do it like this, but it didn't work

```
<div ng-controller="DatesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="d in dates | orderBy:'d':true" ng-bind="d | date:'medium'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `d` in `orderBy`, because this variable doesn't exist when the filter is applied : the array is first filtered, and only then is "repeated".

You must sort the array by each item's actual value. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936078/orderby-array-item-value-in-angular-ng-repeat):

```js
$scope.identity = angular.identity;
$scope.dates = [new Date(2013, 0, 1), new Date(2013, 2, 1), new Date(2013, 1, 1)];
```

```
<div ng-repeat="d in dates | orderBy:identity:true" ng-bind="d | date:'medium'"></div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/7zNHx/)</kbd>