# How to sort array of integers in angularjs using custom filters??

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

here is my code , i dont know what mistake i am doing??? Is there a built in filter or function to sort array of integers or numbers??

```
<body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="controller1" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchbox" />

        <li ng-repeat="num in numbers|filter:searchbox|orderBy:number">
            {{num}}
        </li>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app=angular.module('app', []).controller('controller1', ['$scope', function($scope){


      $scope.numbers=[10,8,6,7];

       $scope.number=function(data)
       {
        return data.sort();
       }

    }


    ]);
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this answer [orderBy array item value in Angular ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936078/orderby-array-item-value-in-angular-ng-repeat)

This means that you can do something like this:

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.numbers = [10,8,6,7];
   $scope.identity = angular.identity;
}]);
```

And

```
<li ng-repeat="num in numbers | orderBy:identity">
   {{num}}
</li>
```