# Sorting with ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an array

```
$scope.answers=["","","",""]
```

means Array have multiple empty elements .

```
<li ng-repeat="item in answers "><input type="text" ng-model="item"/></li>
```

it throws error that duplicate values are not allowed in ng-repeat . if i use

```
<li ng-repeat="item in answers track by $index"><input type="text" ng-model="item"/></li>
```

then its working fine . but i want to use this without track by $index so that sorting on this is also work

Can anybody have idea about this

Comment: Can you delete empty element from your array ?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936078/orderby-array-item-value-in-angular-ng-repeat)

Add this to your controller (as you can't access angular object (other than scope's ones) in your HTML markup)

```
$scope.identity = angular.identity;
```

Then use the following in your HTML and angular will not bother you anymore :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in answers | orderBy : identity track by $index"><input type="text" ng-model="item"/></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use objects inside the array like so:

```
$scope.answers = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}];
```

Then in your view use a property of the empty object.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in answers">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.content"/>
</li>
```

You can see this in action in the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31817drs/).