# Angular js : np-repeat sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am trying to sort the dictionary in angular JS. Below is my code

```
 <table ng-if='dedup==false'  class="table table-hover table-striped"  >
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="value">Count</th>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in result.Fields[0].FieldDistributions|orderBy:value:reverse ">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td> {{value|number}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to sort the table based on the **value** .

What went wrong in the code. Can any one help me ?

UPDATE :

```
{"Fields":[{"FieldName":"Employer","FieldDistributions":{"na":"30724","UK Civil Service":"561","National Health Service":"523","Compass Group":"496","Cit Group Limited":"491","Webrecruit Ltd":"266","Med Team Primary Care Services Limited":"135","Johnson & Johnson":"124","The Allstars Group":"95","Pj Carey Contractors Limited":"88"}}]}
```

This is my response

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For the `orderBy` filter, it's trying to evaluate the property on your scope for a function or string.  So, it's not looking at the current `value` in the list; it's trying `$scope.value` which is probably `undefined`.

Rather, it's expecting a string property on each member of your list (or a function to evaluate the sort with).  For example, if you had a list of people objects that you wanted to sort by name, you would use `orderBy:"name":reverse`.

So, you would just supply whatever property exists on your list members that you want to sort by, or implement a function to compare members of your list and pass that to `orderBy`.

If you're not dealing with objects, but just numeric/string values, then you can do what's suggested in this question: [orderBy array item value in Angular ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936078/orderby-array-item-value-in-angular-ng-repeat).

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 0):

not sure how your modal looks like, but can you give this a try?

```
<table ng-if='dedup==false'  class="table table-hover table-striped"  >
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="value">Count</th>
        <tr ng-repeat="rowData in result.Fields[0].FieldDistributions|orderBy:value:reverse ">
            <td>{{rowData.key}}</td>
            <td> {{rowData.value|number}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I have added my response