# how to set class for variable in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have for example variable 5 which I described in scope, I did range which calculating around this variable, now  I have to show this variable and set the css.class for this variable. How can I do that?

this my example in  `code`   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqren/ZBrJB/58/)

Comment: Could you specify how do you want to "add css to a variable"? Probably you'll have to use ng-class, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that my variable was marked at other color, in example from fiddle, we see range from 0 to 9 with step 3, so we can see 0,3,6,9. I want to see my variable 5 and for example it was in a red color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that returns your preferred css class based on a value:

```
$scope.getClass = function(n) {
    /*example implementation*/
    if (n == 5) {
        return "red";
    } else {
        return "normal";
    }
  };
```

then inside ng-class property use this function:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range(5,15)" ng-class="getClass(n)">test {{n}}</li>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Keammoort/fhc5c1sL/)

UPDATE:

Using your suggestions I've modified my solution. You can solve your problem like this:
Let's assume you have a value set in your scope:

```
$scope.myvalue = 5;
```

then inside range function you'll have to add your value (it can be at the end):

```
$scope.range = function(min, max, step){
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
    input.push($scope.myvalue); //insert value that has to be highlighted
    return input;
  };
```

Then the array before you pass it to ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range(0, 9, 3) | orderBy:identity" ng-class="{'red' : n == myvalue}">test {{n}}</li>
```

and add this to controller (so that orderBy work):

```
$scope.identity = angular.identity;
```

or if you're using AngularJS above 1.3.0-rc5 you can simply use (without *entity* declaration) (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17936284/2127454)):

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range(0, 9, 3) | orderBy" ng-class="{'red' : n == myvalue}">test {{n}}</li>
```

See that in this case you don't need *getClass()* function anymore - you can just compare n to myvalue.

[fiddle with new solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Keammoort/7bm2wnwv/)

Comment: definitely good idea but I have that range was calculated by my way, so we should see the range 0,3, 5(in red color),6,9. But I like you idea, I'll try to play with it

Comment: @Anton so you want to have an extra entry with your variable's value although it's not in array returned by range() function?