# Order by in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I would like to orderby below on card

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="card in myCards | orderBy:'card'">
       <businesscard>{{card}}</businesscard>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myCards = ['J', 'S', 'A'];
});
```

The result i am expecting is,
A
J
S

instead i am getting
J
S
A

Comment: But it is an array you could alphabetically order it

Comment: But how do i do it using angular js in the html using order by clause

Comment: remove the single quotes from `'card'`

Comment: as far as I can see, your link is wroking and sorting by firstnames?

Comment: your fiddle contains an array of objects whereas your question contains an array of values ... these will not behave the same way

Comment: Sorry about that. wrong link. it works if just 'orderBy' is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort by the value, simply provide no parameters to `orderBy` (see [orderBy array item value in Angular ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936078/orderby-array-item-value-in-angular-ng-repeat)):

```
<div ng-repeat="card in myCards | orderBy">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="card in myCards | orderBy:'toString()'">
   <businesscard>{{card}}</businesscard>
</div>
```